# How can I do it properly with Powershell forms?

Tags: winforms, powershell

Recently, I have started getting acquainted with the windows forms in Powershell  and I would like to create a button with a picture on it. The picture appears on a button but in mosaic styles. Is there a solution to keep the picture on the center of the button?

[Here is the picture about what I can see and what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6DVU.png)

Here is my code:

```
$Shutdown_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Shutdown_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(781,115)
$Shutdown_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,90)
$Shutdown_button.Text = "Shutdown"
$Shutdown_button.ForeColor = "Black"
$Shutdown_button.TextAlign = 'BottomCenter'
$Shutdown_button.ImageAlign = 'TopCenter'
$Image_Shutdown = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("$($scriptPath)Source\Images\shutdown.png")
$Shutdown_button.BackgroundImage = $Image_Shutdown
$Shutdown_button.Add_Click($Shutdown_button_Click)

$form_MainForm.Controls.Add($Shutdown_button)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try: $Shutdown_button.BackgroundImageLayout = "Center"

Comment: Super!!! It is working. Thank you a lot. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Please accept it as an answer, so the others can see this question is done.

Comment: Of yourse I accepted :)

Comment: There is no "Powershell Forms" though. It's called "Windows Forms" - you will get better search results by looking for the proper term. (Powershell is based on .NET, Windows Forms is based on .NET, that's why you can use the technology in Powershell, but it's not specific to Powershell.)

Comment: Ok, I got it. It's always good to learn from those people who know better this than me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property `BackgroundImageLayout` from the button.
Like that:

```
$Shutdown_button.BackgroundImageLayout = "Center"
```

Note: Converted my comment to an answer beacuse it was the solution.